# Customizing the PowerPoint Ribbon at Run-Time

Tags: vba, ribbon, powerpoint, ribbonx

I am developing a PowerPoint add-in and would like to temporarily disable some of the Ribbon controls while the add-in application is *running*.

I have developed a solution that works as expected when the Add-In is *enabled*, but this is not really adequate, because it disables some commonly used controls, like SlideMaster, SlideSorter, etc.

I am using PowerPoint 2010.

Here is a sample XML which is well-formed:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
        <tabs>
            <tab idMso="TabView">
                <group idMso="GroupMasterViews" getVisible="GetVisible"/>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Here is a sample callback, taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116890/is-there-a-way-to-use-vba-and-xml-to-add-a-button-to-the-office-2010-ribbon-depe):

```
Sub GetVisible(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal As Boolean)
    If TrapFlag Then
        returnedVal = False ' control is hidden
    Else:
        returnedVal = True  ' control is not hidden
    End If
End Sub
```

When I navigate to the `View` ribbon, an alert informs me that:

> The macro cannot be found or has been disabled because of your security settings.

Presumably this is referring to the `GetVisible` macro? My macro settings are:

- Enable all macros (not recommended)
- Trust access to the VBA project object model

I have been struggling with what I have found so far but so far unable to implement suggestions. Most answers are specific to Excel. I have not really found anything specific to PowerPoint, but figured it should not be terribly difficult to port code from one application to another, as I have done this for many other things in VBA.

I have also tried [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee767705(v=office.14).aspx) method, but the `SetCustomUI` is not available in PowerPoint at the `Application` or `Presentation` level, perhaps it is unique or only applicable to Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After quite a bit of trial & error, I believe I have a functional solution, although there are some things I am not certain about which I will describe below.

I have tested this in a PPTM file with a subroutine to control the public `TrapFlag` variable, which determines whether to hide/disable certain controls.  I have also tested this in a PPAM where this flag is set when the application launches, **not** when the Add-In is loaded.

**This allows me to manipulate the RibbonUI at runtime.**

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`
   <customUI onLoad="RibbonOnLoad" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
     <commands>
       <command idMso="ViewSlideSorterView" getEnabled="EnableControl"/>
       <command idMso="ViewNotesPageView" getEnabled="EnableControl"/>
       <command idMso="ViewSlideShowReadingView" getEnabled="EnableControl"/>
       <command idMso="ViewSlideMasterView" getEnabled="EnableControl"/>
       <command idMso="ViewHandoutMasterView" getEnabled="EnableControl"/>
       <command idMso="ViewNotesMasterView" getEnabled="EnableControl"/>
       <command idMso="WindowNew" getEnabled="EnableControl"/>
   </commands>
   <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
       <tabs>
           <tab idMso="TabView">
               <group idMso="GroupMasterViews" getVisible="VisibleGroup"/>
               <group idMso="GroupPresentationViews" getVisible="VisibleGroup"/>
           </tab>
       </tabs>
   </ribbon>
```

Here is the VBA callbacks, generated from the CustomUI Editor application, modified as per my requirements.

```
Option Explicit
Public TrapFlag As Boolean
Public Rib As IRibbonUI
Public xmlID As String

Public Sub SetFlag()
Dim mbResult As Integer
    mbResult = MsgBox("Do you want to disable some controls on the Ribbon?", vbYesNo)
    If mbResult = vbYes Then
        TrapFlag = True
    Else:
        TrapFlag = False
    End If
End Sub

'Callback for customUI.onLoad
Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    'MsgBox "onLoad"
    Set Rib = ribbon
End Sub

'I use this Callback for disabling some Controls:
'   ViewSlideSorterView
'   ViewNotesPageView
'   ViewSlideShowReadingView
'   ViewSlideMasterView
'   ViewHandoutMasterView
'   ViewNotesMasterView
'   WindowNew
Sub EnableControl(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    returnedVal = Not TrapFlag 'TrapFlag = True indicates the Application is running.
    'MsgBox ("GetEnabled for " & control.Id)
    'Debug.Print control.Id & " enabled = " & CStr(returnedVal)
    Call RefreshRibbon(control.Id)
End Sub

'I use this Callback for disabling/hiding some tab groups:
'   GroupMasterViews
'   GroupPresentationViews
Sub VisibleGroup(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    returnedVal = Not TrapFlag 'TrapFlag = True indicates the Application is running.
    'MsgBox "GetVisible for " & control.Id
    'Debug.Print control.Id & " enabled = " & CStr(returnedVal)
    Call RefreshRibbon(control.Id)
End Sub

Sub RefreshRibbon(Id As String)
    xmlID = Id
    'MsgBox "Refreshing ribbon for " & Id, vbInformation
    If Rib Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Error, Save/Restart your Presentation"
    Else
        Rib.Invalidate
    End If
End Sub
```

**Some uncertainties**

- I am still not entirely sure what some Ron deBruin's code does ([here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win012.htm)), or whether it is necessary. I have done some testing and I do not really sure that the public variable `xmlID` is necessary in this case. He uses that somehow which I cannot understand.
- Also, I am not able to use the same callback on the tab `group` as I
  use on the `command` in the XML, so I use the tag `getEnabled` for
  the commands, but I have to use `getVisible` for the groups.   These
  are tied to the callback functions `EnableControl` and
  `VisibleGroup`, respectively.  In any case, `VisibleGroup` seems to
  disable the groups, so functionally it is the same.
- I also believe that the `getEnabled` tag will prevent hotkey and programmatic access to those commands that I disable.