# How to block/disable Refresh All from the excel 2007 ribbon

Tags: excel, vba

I have given a button to the user to populate the data from sql oledb connections. That does the job so I can control when user should populate the data from query tables.  My problem is, I have no way of  blocking user pressing    ‘Refresh All ‘ button from the ribbon.

Tried the following code in Public Sub Workbook_Open() 
'

```
        '-- Turn off the Refresh Capability from Ribbon
        For J = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count

           With ActiveWorkbook.Connections(J).OLEDBConnection
             .BackgroundQuery = False
             .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
           End With

          'MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Connections(J).Name
        Next J
```

It doesn’t work. 'Refresh All' is still active and populates all worksheets.

Please let me know how to block ‘Refresh All’ from the ribbon or a way  Not Refresh, when user presses that button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your only option may be to try and disable the Refresh All button, but I've never done anything like that.

[This thread](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=204203) seemed to show a way to do it.
[This site](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section2.htm) by Ron de Bruin has a lot of helpful information.
And [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043318/hide-individual-custom-ribbon-buttons) has some helpful information.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I'll see what I can do.