# How to disable Refresh All button in excel workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm looking to see if there is a way to disable the Refresh All button in excel workbook to prevent the user from refreshing his data.

Comment: That sounds counter-productive. Can you explain WHY you would want your users to NOT refresh? Please edit your question to provide that information, then post a comment to alert your followers.

Comment: Research ahead. Good luck! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561446/how-to-block-disable-refresh-all-from-the-excel-2007-ribbon

Answer (score 2):

If you set the Protection on a sheet and also un-tick the 'Refresh this connection on Refresh All' then the Refresh All should have no effect on the sheet.  If you then wanted a the user to refresh you could do this through VBA.  I have done this on a number of workbooks to control the update of external data.