# Powerpoint: dynamically control getEnabled using Tags

Tags: xml, vba, powerpoint, ribbonx

I'm trying to have my custom ribbon enable different buttons when the selection meet certain criteria, I'm not sure if I have the right approach, but I have:

a class module with the following:

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents PPTEvent As Application

Private Sub PPTEvent_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
    refreshRibbon ""
End Sub
```

an event handler:

```
Option Explicit
Public cPPTObject As New cEventClass
Public TrapFlag As Boolean

Sub TrapEvents()
    Set cPPTObject.PPTEvent = Application
    TrapFlag = True
End Sub

Sub ReleaseTrap()
    If TrapFlag = True Then
       Set cPPTObject.PPTEvent = Nothing
       Set cPPTObject = Nothing
       TrapFlag = False
    End If
End Sub
```

and the code:

```
Option Explicit
Public myRibbon As IRibbonUI
Public myTag As String

Sub OnRibbonLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    TrapEvents
    Set myRibbon = ribbon
End Sub

Sub getEnabled(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    
    Select Case True
        Case ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionShapes
            returnedVal = True
            Call refreshRibbon(Tag:="Shape")
        Case ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count = 1
            returnedVal = True
            Call refreshRibbon(Tag:="ShapeOne")
        Case ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count = 2
            returnedVal = True
            Call refreshRibbon(Tag:="ShapeTwo")
    End Select
    
End Sub

Sub refreshRibbon(Tag As String)
    myTag = Tag
    If myRibbon Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Error, Save/Restart your Presentation"
    Else
        myRibbon.Invalidate
    End If
End Sub
```

Above is a simplified version of what I want to achieve but the concept is the same. The XML for the three buttons is:

```
     <button id="Shape" size="large" label="Shape" 
        tag="Shape" 
        getEnabled="getEnabled" />
     <button id="ShapeOne" size="large" label="ShapeOne" 
        tag="ShapeOne" 
        getEnabled="getEnabled" />
     <button id="ShapeTwo" size="large" label="ShapeTwo" 
        tag="ShapeTwo" 
        getEnabled="getEnabled" />
```

Currently, when I select any number or combination of shapes, all three buttons become enabled. I am only able to get each button to be enabled one by one by changing `myRibbon.Invalidate` to `myRibbon.InvalidateControl("ShapeOne")` and so on.

I've taken inspiration from a [Ron de Bruin's excel example](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win013.htm) and David Zemen's answer to [Powerpoint VBA/Macro: Deactivate (Grey out) Button on Ribbon, if no shape is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313097/powerpoint-vba-macro-deactivate-grey-out-button-on-ribbon-if-no-shape-is-sel)

Questions I have are:

Why do the second and third cases produce a selection(unknown member) error? i include a `on error goto EH` to bypass this and get the code to run.

How do i tie the tags to the invalidate command, is there a way to incorporate `Tag` variable into InvalidateControl, to get something dynamic like `myRibbon.InvalidateControl (Tag)`?

Not sure if the approach is correct but ideally I would like to have the one `getEnabled` hook for all the buttons utilising the tags.

Comment: The second and third cases produce a selection(unknown member) error because if no shape selected you can't check the `ShapeRange.Count` property. Check the `Selection.Type = ppSelectionShapes` first in all the cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub getEnabled(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    returnVal = False
    If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionShapes Then
       Select Case control.Id
           Case "Shape"
               returnedVal = True
           Case "ShapeOne"
               returnedVal = (ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count = 1)
           Case "ShapeTwo"
               returnedVal = (ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count = 2)
       End Select
   End If
End Sub
```

Delete `refreshRibbon` sub and in your `PPT_Event_WindowSelectionChange`, just invalidate the entire ribbon

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents PPTEvent As Application

Private Sub PPTEvent_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
    If myRibbon Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Error, Save/Restart your Presentation"
    Else
        myRibbon.Invalidate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will give this a go tonight after work and let you know if you helped.

Comment: @Kevin I'm not sure if loss of ribbon state occurs in PowerPoint as well (I assume so since you test `If myRibbon Is Nothing`) but this [post](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-to-preserve-or-regain-the-id-of-my-custom-ribbon-ui.518629/#post-2562883) shows a workaround to preserve the ribbon object that you can consider for your ribbon (the post shows a solution for Excel environment but you can adapt similar concept for PowerPoint environment)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (tested):

### Ribbon XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="OnRibbonLoad" >
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="MyTab01" label="MyTab">
                <group id="MyGroup01" label="MyGroup">
                    <button id="Shape" imageMso="AnimationCustomAddEmphasisDialog" size="large" label="Shape" 
                        tag="Shape" 
                        getEnabled="getEnabled" />
                     <button id="ShapeOne" imageMso="AnimationCustomAddEntranceDialog" size="large" label="ShapeOne" 
                        tag="ShapeOne" 
                        getEnabled="getEnabled" />
                     <button id="ShapeTwo" imageMso="AnimationCustomAddExitDialog" size="large" label="ShapeTwo" 
                        tag="ShapeTwo" 
                        getEnabled="getEnabled" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

### cEventClass class module

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents PPTEvent As Application

Private Sub PPTEvent_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
    Dim button
    For Each button In buttons
        myRibbon.InvalidateControl button
    Next
End Sub
```

### RegularModule

```
Option Explicit

Public cPPTObject As New cEventClass, myRibbon As IRibbonUI, buttons As Variant

Sub OnRibbonLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set myRibbon = ribbon
    Set cPPTObject.PPTEvent = Application
    buttons = Array("Shape", "ShapeOne", "ShapeTwo")  'button's ID's
End Sub

Sub getEnabled(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef enabled)
    Dim i As Integer
    With ActiveWindow.Selection
        enabled = False
        If .Type = ppSelectionShapes Then
            For i = 0 To UBound(buttons)
                If control.Tag = buttons(i) And IIf(i > 0, .ShapeRange.Count = i, True) Then
                    enabled = True
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'll try this and let you know how I go thanks.