# Improve resolution of custom ribbon button

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I've been building custom ribbon buttons for Excel using the excellent post [How to add a custom Ribbon tab using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850836/how-to-add-a-custom-ribbon-tab-using-vba)

What I want to know is how to increase the resolution of a custom button when it is imported to Excel.  For example, this is what my buttons look like in Excel

[image: s]

I would prefer it to look like

[image]

Any ideas?

These are the images I am using:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwrHExCJDztETFRmSkszV1V3OUk/edit?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwrHExCJDztERlJsdlMzRzliUkE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share the actual image that you are using? I guess you need to use a better image. Also this question is off topic for Stack Overflow and is better suited for SuperUser.

Comment: Thanks, will post there.  Should have mentioned I have tried a number of resolutions and formats without much success.  Cheers,

Comment: May I see few icons that you tried?

Comment: Ok I checked it. It is a slightly bigger picture and hence when the dimensions are reduced then the pic get pixelated. You will have to recreate a smaller size of it so that Excel uses the original picture without adjusting the size.