# Creating a button on Excel Ribbon to open Userform Window

Tags: excel, vba, addition, userform

I have developed a VBA userform interface that allows the user to input values, have it calculate results, and then print them out into the worksheet.  I am wondering if there is any possible way that I can have a button on the excel ribbon, say under the "Data" tab for instance, that would elicit the userform interface to open.

Currently the only way I can use the interface is by Developer>>Visual Basic>>Clicking on Userform>>F5. This also limits the userform in that it can only be used in one particular workbook as opposed to many. Or if it was somehow possible, to make it an add-in instead.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a custom Ribbon tab using VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850836/how-to-add-a-custom-ribbon-tab-using-vba)

Comment: Plenty of examples on Ron's site also http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691832%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to add custom tab and/or button to Ribbon is to use [Custom UI Editor Tool for MS Office Ribbon](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2006/05/26/customuieditor.aspx). Follow the links provided in comments to your question too. There you'll find many useful information.