# Hide/Show newly created tab in Microsoft Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, ribbon

I am new to VBA. I am using Excel 2010.

I am trying to create a new Tab (Ex:Trends) beside the existing Data tab.
I want to show/Hide a tab (Trends) based on the column selected.
If I select Column A, the tab (Trends) should show and if I select column B the tab (Trends) should hide.

How I can achieve the above functionality?

Do we need a macro to achieve this or is there any alternative?

[image]

Comment: Please show your code. This should include the Ribbon XML AND the VBA callbacks associated with same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a custom Ribbon tab using VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850836/how-to-add-a-custom-ribbon-tab-using-vba)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a duplicate of "How to add a custom Ribbon tab using VBA?" - see the post with answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8850836/2658159).

Additionally, Microsoft Developer Network has some useful tips on this - you may check out the article "Adding Custom UI to Excel 2010 Worksheets," accessible for free on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh832141%28v=office.14%29.aspx).