# Package a Ribbon with a Custom VBA Add In for Microsoft Office

Tags: excel, office-2010, vba

I am working with Excel 2010 but I assume the idea is constant accross all of Office 2010.

I am making an Add in to have some VBA Macros that will work with all of my files and would like to make a ribbon that has buttons bound to these macros. I know how to make a ribbon through Excel Options --> Customize Ribbon but I would like to make one that is shown whenever the Add In is active. This is so I can distribute the Add in with an easy way to run the macros.

Is there a way I can do this? Thanks

UPDATE:

I have read into it and with what I have at my disposal here (Office 2010 and notepad) I am going to have to make the ribbon as an XML document and then put that with my `xlam` file. I am just not sure on the specifics at this point.

Comment: Yes - start here: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section2.htm

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at Andy Pope's Ribbon Editor.  It is boss when it comes to editing the Ribbon and wiring up VBA code.  http://www.andypope.info/vba/ribboneditor.htm

Comment: Do you develop a VSTO based add-in?

Comment: No, I am pretty much limeted to text editors and VBA editor within Office....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it by hand based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29090690/2497001).

Worked well, just a little tricky working with zipping the Excel Files. Never Unzip the entinre file, just open it with explorer and copy files into it and it worked well!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are developing a VSTO based add-in. If so, you have two ways to go:

1. VSTO provides a Ribbon designer which you can use to build the custom UI. See [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using the Ribbon Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386104.aspx) to get started quickly.
2. The other way is to use the Ribbon XML markup for buidling a custom UI (available for all kind of add-ins). See [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using the Ribbon Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386104.aspx) for more information.

In general, the Fluent UI ( aka Ribbon UI) is described in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Based on OP mentioning "VBA macros" I suspect this is in the `xlam` world.  Item 2 from your list is relevant there, although the Ribbon Editor add-in is much easier to use than editing the XML directly.

Comment: I am working with an `.xlam` file, and I dont have access to VSTO, just the built in VBA editor and text editors...

Comment: From what I can tell there is a way to make an XML file that has the items of the ribbon, then unzip the `.xlam` file and put it in there, I just am not solid on the details yet