# Custom Excel Ribbon Button missing

Tags: excel, ribbonx, vba

I create a custom button in the excel ribbon that will call a Macro. After I save the .xlsm file and try to open it in another PC, the custom button is gone.

What should I do to make custom button always there even when I open it in another machine?

Comment: the custom button is not saved by the workbook. It is in your Excel itself. All you can do is going for an open-event do get it there like [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850836/how-to-add-a-custom-ribbon-tab-using-vba)

Comment: Have you saved the code to your personal section?