# Adding custom tabs in excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I found the code below on stackoverflow to add custom tabs using vba. It works but it only works if I go into the code editor mode. The reports menu only shows up when i go into the code by pressing alt+f11

I have called the loadcustribbon in workbook_open event

```
Sub LoadCustRibbon()

Dim hFile As Long
Dim path As String, fileName As String, ribbonXML As String, user As String

hFile = FreeFile
user = Environ("Username")
path = "C:\Users\" & user & "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\"
fileName = "Excel.officeUI"

ribbonXML = "<mso:customUI      xmlns:mso='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui'>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "  <mso:ribbon>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "    <mso:qat/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "    <mso:tabs>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "      <mso:tab id='reportTab' label='Reports' insertBeforeQ='mso:TabFormat'>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        <mso:group id='reportGroup' label='Reports' autoScale='true'>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:button id='runReport' label='PTO' "   & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "imageMso='AppointmentColor3'      onAction='GenReport'/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        </mso:group>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "      </mso:tab>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "    </mso:tabs>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "  </mso:ribbon>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "</mso:customUI>"

ribbonXML = Replace(ribbonXML, """", "")

Open path & fileName For Output Access Write As hFile
Print #hFile, ribbonXML
Close hFile

End Sub

Sub ClearCustRibbon()

Dim hFile As Long
Dim path As String, fileName As String, ribbonXML As String, user As String

hFile = FreeFile
user = Environ("Username")
path = "C:\Users\" & user & "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\"
fileName = "Excel.officeUI"

ribbonXML = "<mso:customUI           xmlns:mso=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"">" & _
"<mso:ribbon></mso:ribbon></mso:customUI>"

Open path & fileName For Output Access Write As hFile
Print #hFile, ribbonXML
Close hFile

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need to add the tabs that way? I recommend using the Custom UI Editor to embed the ribbon xml in the excel-file, as per [this q+a](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8852767/1490783).

Comment: I would embed to, you have the XML so add it in the file.

Comment: it works flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Macro use Custom UI Editor to customize your menus/ribbon.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm