# add-in not working from custom UI

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I'm trying to create my first add-in with Custom UI based on this [guidance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg597509(v=office.14).aspx). (As I don't have Visual Studio I'm working with VBA; Excel 2013 in Windows 7)

For testing I've just created one sub in a module:

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox "test"
End Sub
```

As described in the guidance, I've created CustomUI folder with CustomUI.xml in it. CustomUI.xml's content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="TestTab" label="Test tab" >
        <group id="TestGroup" label="Test group" >
          <button id="test" visible="true" size="large" 
                  label="Test Sub" 
                  onAction="test" />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Also added
`https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg597509(v=office.14).aspx`
to .rels as described.

Now I've the add-in loading correctly, the only issue that clicking on the newly created ribbon item I'm keep getting below error message (of course the macro works correctly when I start it from VBA editor):
[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850836/how-to-add-a-custom-ribbon-tab-using-vba/8852767#8852767) I have explained it in a very simple way.

Comment: especially this part `Public Sub Callback1(control As IRibbonControl)`

Comment: thanks for the comment! I've tried it, but still has the same issue:( (I've restarted excel after edit if that matters).

Comment: What error did you get? the same?

Comment: yes, still the same

Comment: I just tested it. it works just fine for me

Comment: Are you sure the message is for that. Is there any other code in your workbook?

Comment: no, there isn't any other code there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have incorporated `Public Sub test(control As IRibbonControl)` as suggetsed [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850836/how-to-add-a-custom-ribbon-tab-using-vba/8852767#8852767) and if you are still getting the error then I believe that there is some other code in one of the open Workbooks/Add-In which is interfering with this code.

1. Close all other open workbooks
2. Check for any other installed Add-Ins.

Answer (score 1):

Add ' control As IRibbonControl ' as argument to your subroutine.

For example if the name of your subroutine is ' test ', then

```
Sub test(control As IRibbonControl)
    'your code goes here
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I've tried it, but still has the same issue:( (I've restarted excel after edit if that matters)

Comment: this could be because you are having your code in a private module [ eg : ThisWorkbook or Sheet1 ] Try inserting a new module and insert the code there. This will solve the issue. When i inserted the code in ' ThisWorkbook ' module it gave me the error but not when put in a new module (public module; say 'Module1')

Comment: It was already in a "module", the issue was having also another workbook with a sub called "test". Thanks again for your effort!