# How to create an addin with a toolbar in it

Tags: vba, excel, toolbar, add-in

I am struggling to find a solution to my problem.

I designed several UserForms and wrote many functions in a Workbook, and I added a new toolbar with buttons that call those functions.

Now what I want is to save this Workbook as an add-in so that when I add the add-in on another PC the toolbars appear.

But the toolbars does not appear. I could save the Workbook as an add-in with all the functions and the UserForms, but I couldn't get the toolbar.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you placed your file in the XLStart folder? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-how-Excel-starts-6509b9af-2cc8-4fb6-9ef5-cf5f1d292c19

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a custom Ribbon tab using VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850836/how-to-add-a-custom-ribbon-tab-using-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By no means a solution, but maybe the following provides a starting point:

From what you say I assume you managed

- to activate your *.xlam add-in on another pc
- you could access all it's vba-code and userforms
- you could **not** access it's CustomUI-ribbon

Check if your final `*.xlam` still has the toolbar the toolbar in it when you deploy it:

- make a backup of your ready-to-deploy add-in file (`*.xlam`).
- open the file, either by changing it's file extension to `.zip`. (There is no need to rename it if you're using a file archiver like [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.de/))
- the contents of the file `\customUI\customUI.xml` should roughly resemble the following.

**Example XML:**

```
<customUI
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui"
xmlns:shared="sharedNamespace"
onLoad="onLoadRibbonDB"
>
 <ribbon>
    <tabs>
        <tab idQ="shared:tabControls" label="AddIn_Beispiele" >

            <group id="grpA" label="Buttons">
                <button id="buttonA" label="Button_large" image="bunny2" onAction="buttonA_Click" size="large"/>
            </group>    

        </tab>
    </tabs>
 </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Note that Excel won't show the ribbon if there are even minor errors in it. For testing, exclude anything that could result in an error, then re-introduce your ribbon controls step by step. If found the following the most common:

- id's are not distinct (e.g. used in other ribbons / add-ins)
- custom icons are not formatted correctly
- custom icons are not referenced correctly

**Off-topic:** if you plan to deploy the file across numerous PCs, a simple macro like the following could work for you:

```
Sub InstallAddIn()

    On Error GoTo skpError

    Dim path as String
    path = "L:\SQL_AddIn\SQL_AddIn_V1.0.xlam"
    name = "SQL_AddIn_V1.0"

    ' Copy the file
    With New FileSystemObject
        .CopyFile _
            path _
            , "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\"
    End With

    ' Add-In Aktivieren
    AddIns(name).Installed = True
    MsgBox ws1.Cells(1, 2).Value & " installiert.", vbInformation
    Exit Sub

skpError:
    MsgBox "Fehler #" & Err & vbNewLine & Error

End Sub
```