# Ribbon button not open original macro file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro attached to a button in a custom ribbon. I want to have variants of this file and I won't be the only one using this file. However, if I even just do a Save As and change the file name and I press the button it has to open the old excel file to run it. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Try convert it into a `.xltm` - macro enabled excel template as the master one. New files based on this template also needs to be macro enabled workbook `.xlsm`

Comment: Maybe this  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850836/how-to-add-a-custom-ribbon-tab-using-vba) will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is what I did and it worked. Thank for the answers