# Create New Tab in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a New Tab with Custom Buttons when user opens a Macro Enabled Worksheet (.xlsm).  Below is code I’ve used previously in the ThisWorkbook module of my macro; however, the buttons display under the “Add-in” tab. 
My goal is to add the buttons under a custom tab with custom sections if possible. Thank you.

```
'Stored in ThisWorkbook module of my macro
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

            Dim CmdBar As CommandBar
            Dim CmdBarMenu As CommandBarControl
            Dim CmdBarMenuItem As CommandBarControl

            Set CmdBar = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar")
            Set CmdBarMenu = CmdBar.Controls("Tools")

            On Error Resume Next
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                CmdBarMenu.Controls(Button).Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            On Error GoTo 0

            Set CmdBarMenuItem = CmdBarMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            With CmdBarMenuItem
                .Caption = Button
                .OnAction = “NameOfMyMacro"
                .FaceId = 5872
                .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaptionBelow
            End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: This type of code always creates the controls in the Add-ins tab: you can't place them anywhere else since Excel 2007

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually change the .XML on the user interface, or use a software which does that for you.

See the links below:

[How to add a custom Ribbon tab using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850836/how-to-add-a-custom-ribbon-tab-using-vba)
http://www.contextures.com/excelribbonaddcustomtab.html