# excel ribbon dropdown items - no onAction?

Tags: xml, excel, ribbon, vba

I have created a custom tab with a dropdown that has both items and buttons in it. I can get the onAction macro to run for a button, but cannot do the same for an item. Should this be possible? I have seen plenty of examples with onAction macros specified for items, but none seem to work. I also have an add-in witten in visual studio that has what appear to be items in a dropdown that call macros.

My code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()

' copied from here:
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850836/how-to-add-a-custom-ribbon-tab-using-vba


Dim hFile As Long
Dim path As String, fileName As String, ribbonXML As String, user As String

hFile = FreeFile
user = Environ("Username")
path = "C:\Users\" & user & "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\"
fileName = "Excel.officeUI"

ribbonXML = "<mso:customUI      xmlns:mso='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui'>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "<mso:ribbon><mso:qat/><mso:tabs><mso:tab id='x' label='Development' insertBeforeQ='mso:TabFormat'>" & vbNewLine 'insertAfterQ='x1:IDC_TEAM_TAB' id='mso_c1.1C4ECC7'
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "<mso:group id='mso_c2.1C4ECD7' label='Group1' imageMso='Risks' autoScale='true'>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "<mso:dropDown id='dropDown' label='Test Menu:' onAction='test_macro'>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "   <mso:item id='item1' label='Item 1' onAction='test_macro'/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "   <mso:item id='item2' label='Item 2'  onAction='test_macro'/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "   <mso:item id='item3' label='Item 3'  onAction='test_macro'/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "   <mso:button id='button' label='Button...' onAction='test_macro'/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + " </mso:dropDown>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "</mso:group>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "<mso:group id='mso_c3.1C56531' label='Group 2' imageMso='ListMacros' autoScale='true'/>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "</mso:tab></mso:tabs></mso:ribbon></mso:customUI>"

ribbonXML = Replace(ribbonXML, """", "")

Open path & fileName For Output Access Write As hFile
Print #hFile, ribbonXML
Close hFile

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()

Dim hFile As Long
Dim path As String, fileName As String, ribbonXML As String, user As String

hFile = FreeFile
user = Environ("Username")
path = "C:\Users\" & user & "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\"
fileName = "Excel.officeUI"

ribbonXML = "<mso:customUI           xmlns:mso=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"">" & _
"<mso:ribbon></mso:ribbon></mso:customUI>"

Open path & fileName For Output Access Write As hFile
Print #hFile, ribbonXML
Close hFile

End Sub
```

and:

```
Sub test_macro()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(1, 1) = "test"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an 'onaction' with the dropdown. You get an index for the item. In my example, you can chose between 3 languages in a dropdown in Excel UI ribbon. First item "English" is 0, second item "Français" is 1, and my third item "Nederlands" is 2. In blue what I adapt in xml:    [image]

and in VBA, like for a button, I change my named constant value (or do whatever you want).

`Sub DDonAction(control As IRibbonControl, id As String, index As Variant)
    Select Case control.id 'Case dropdown if multiple dropdowns
        Case "DDLanguage"
           Select Case index
                Case 0 'Action if English is selected
                  ActiveWorkbook.Names("Language").RefersToR1C1 = "=""Eng"""
                Case 1 'Action if 'Français' is selected
                  ActiveWorkbook.Names("Language").RefersToR1C1 = "=""Fr"""
                Case 2 'Action if Nederlands is selected
                  ActiveWorkbook.Names("Language").RefersToR1C1 = "=""Nl"""
           End Select 'item
    End Select 'Dropdown
End Sub`