# Why does my number to text code not work?

Tags: excel, vba

This function is supposed to let you convert dollar and cent amounts to words with a formula, so 22.50 would read as Twenty-Two Dollars and Fifty Cents. The formula for this is =SpellNumber(A1)

I seem to be having issues. I got this code straight from Microsoft's website so I do not understand why it would not work. I am quite new to vba and would appreciate some pointers to fix this.  Thank you in advance for your help!

```
     Option Explicit

'Main Function

Function SpellNumber(ByVal MyNumber)

Dim Dollars, Cents, Temp

Dim DecimalPlace, Count

ReDim Place(9) As String

Place(2) = " Thousand "

Place(3) = " Million "

Place(4) = " Billion "

Place(5) = " Trillion "

' String representation of amount.

MyNumber = Trim(Str(MyNumber))

' Position of decimal place 0 if none.

DecimalPlace = InStr(MyNumber, ".")

' Convert cents and set MyNumber to dollar amount.

If DecimalPlace > 0 Then
' <-- Edit: remove incorrect line break = underscore character -->
Cents = GetTens(Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & _ "00", 2))

MyNumber = Trim(Left(MyNumber, DecimalPlace - 1))

End If

Count = 1

Do While MyNumber <> ""

Temp = GetHundreds(Right(MyNumber, 3))

If Temp <> "" Then Dollars = Temp & Place(Count) & Dollars

If Len(MyNumber) > 3 Then

MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 3)

Else

MyNumber = ""

End If

Count = Count + 1

Loop

Select Case Dollars

Case ""

Dollars = "No Dollars"

Case "One"

Dollars = "One Dollar"

Case Else

Dollars = Dollars & " Dollars"

End Select

Select Case Cents

Case ""

Cents = " and No Cents"

Case "One"

Cents = " and One Cent"

Case Else

Cents = " and " & Cents & " Cents"

End Select

SpellNumber = Dollars & Cents

End Function


' Converts a number from 100-999 into text

Function GetHundreds(ByVal MyNumber)

Dim Result As String

If Val(MyNumber) = 0 Then Exit Function

MyNumber = Right("000" & MyNumber, 3)

' Convert the hundreds place.

If Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1) <> "0" Then

Result = GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1)) & " Hundred "

End If

' Convert the tens and ones place.

If Mid(MyNumber, 2, 1) <> "0" Then

Result = Result & GetTens(Mid(MyNumber, 2))

Else

Result = Result & GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 3))

End If

GetHundreds = Result

End Function


' Converts a number from 10 to 99 into text.


 Function GetTens(TensText)

Dim Result As String

Result = "" ' Null out the temporary function value.

If Val(Left(TensText, 1)) = 1 Then ' If value between 10-19...

Select Case Val(TensText)

Case 10: Result = "Ten"

Case 11: Result = "Eleven"

Case 12: Result = "Twelve"

Case 13: Result = "Thirteen"

Case 14: Result = "Fourteen"

Case 15: Result = "Fifteen"

Case 16: Result = "Sixteen"

Case 17: Result = "Seventeen"

Case 18: Result = "Eighteen"

Case 19: Result = "Nineteen"

Case Else

End Select

Else ' If value between 20-99...

Select Case Val(Left(TensText, 1))

Case 2: Result = "Twenty "

Case 3: Result = "Thirty "

 Case 4: Result = "Forty "

Case 5: Result = "Fifty "

Case 6: Result = "Sixty "

 Case 7: Result = "Seventy "

Case 8: Result = "Eighty "

Case 9: Result = "Ninety "

Case Else

End Select
' <-- Edit incorrect line break -->
Result = Result & GetDigit _

(Right(TensText, 1)) ' Retrieve ones place. 

End If

GetTens = Result

End Function


 ' Converts a number from 1 to 9 into text.

 Function GetDigit(Digit)

 Select Case Val(Digit)

Case 1: GetDigit = "One"

Case 2: GetDigit = "Two"

Case 3: GetDigit = "Three"

Case 4: GetDigit = "Four"

Case 5: GetDigit = "Five"

Case 6: GetDigit = "Six"

Case 7: GetDigit = "Seven"

Case 8: GetDigit = "Eight"

Case 9: GetDigit = "Nine"

Case Else: GetDigit = ""

End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Remove the subsequent blank code line immediately after code lines with an underscore at the end (`"_"`) as this marks line breaks; thus an additional line in between cannot be read correctly by VBA.

Comment: Related link: [Convert numbers to words with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204004/convert-numbers-to-words-with-vba/51204358#51204358)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've reformatted the code improperly. The `_` character notes a new code line that continues from the previous without additional line feeds. You've either removed the linefeed or misplaced the `_` character altogether.

```
'This,
Cents = GetTens(Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & _ "00", 2))

'should have been,
Cents = GetTens(Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & "00", 2))
'or,
Cents = GetTens(Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & _
   "00", 2))


'This,
Result = Result & GetDigit _

(Right(TensText, 1)) ' Retrieve ones place.

'should have been,
Result = Result & GetDigit(Right(TensText, 1)) ' Retrieve ones place.
'or,
Result = Result & GetDigit _
   (Right(TensText, 1)) ' Retrieve ones place.
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote new code.

```
Function NumbertoString(sNum As String)
    Dim s As String
    Dim vDigit(), vR(), vMod()
    Dim Digit1000
    Dim sDal As String, sCent As String
    Dim Cent As String, Num As String
    Dim i As Integer, x As Integer, k As Integer

    If InStr(sNum, ".") Then
        s = Split(sNum, ".")(0)
        Cent = Split(sNum, ".")(1)
    Else
        s = sNum
        Cent = ""
    End If

    Digit1000 = Array("", "", " Thousand ", " Million ", " Billion ", " Trillion ")
    k = Len(s)
    x = k Mod 3
    n = Int(k / 3)
    If n = 0 Then GoTo p
    ReDim vDigit(1 To n)

    '@@If the length of the number is a multiple of 3
    For i = 1 To n
        st = k - i * 3 + 1
        vDigit(i) = Mid(s, st, 3)
    Next i
    '@@If the length of the number is NOT a multiple of 3
p:
    If x > 0 Then
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vDigit(1 To n)
        vDigit(n) = Left(s, x)
    End If
    For i = n To 1 Step -1
          Num = Num & getString(vDigit(i)) & Digit1000(i)
    Next i
    Select Case Num
        Case ""
            sDal = " No Dallar "
        Case "One"
            sDal = " Dallar "
        Case Else
            sDal = " Dallars "
    End Select

    Select Case getString(Val(Cent))
        Case ""
            sCent = "and No Cents"
        Case "One"
            sCent = " Cent"
        Case Else
            sCent = " Cents"
    End Select
    NumbertoString = Num & sDal & " and " & getString(Val(Cent)) & sCent
End Function

Function getString(s)
    Dim vDigit(), vR(), vMod()
    Dim n As Integer, i As Long
    Dim Num As String

    dig1 = Array("", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine")
    dig10 = Array("Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen")
    dig20 = Array("", "", "Twenty ", "Thirty ", "Forty ", "Fitty ", "Sixty ", "Seventy ", "Eighty", "Ninety ")
    If s = "" Then Exit Function
    Do Until (s / 10) < i
        n = n + 1
        i = 10 ^ n
        ReDim Preserve vDigit(1 To n)
        vDigit(n) = i
    Loop
    ReDim vMod(1 To n)
    For i = 1 To n
        vMod(i) = s Mod vDigit(i)
    Next i
    ReDim vR(1 To n + 1)

    vR(1) = vMod(1)
    For i = 2 To n
        vR(i) = Int((vMod(i) - vMod(i - 1)) / vDigit(i - 1))
    Next i
    vR(n + 1) = Int((s - vMod(n)) / vDigit(n))

    Select Case vR(2)
        Case 0
            Num = dig1(vR(1))
        Case 1
            Num = dig10(vR(1))
        Case Else
            Num = dig20(vR(2)) & dig1(vR(1))
    End Select
    If UBound(vR) = 3 Then
        Num = dig1(vR(3)) & " Hundred " & Num
    End If
    getString = Num
End Function
```

Result image
[image]

Comment: Nice solution +1). - Due to **internationalization** I'd suggest to insert the following code line into your main function (after declarations): `sNum = Str(sNum)` in order to force a string actually including a **decimal point**, as for instance central European countries use a comma as number separator. *Minor hint: some missing variable declarations, "Dollars" instead of "Dallars".*