# Convert Number into Words in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below codes for converting number to words. But how can I edit the code for numbers with no decimals, and the "and" is located at the correct position.

E.g.

250 - Two Hundred Fifty Dollars and No Cents.

250 - Ringgit Malaysia Two Hundred **and** Fifty

In the first place, I wish to have the correct "and" position

In the second place, the currency can be placed at the beginning

```
'Main Function
Function SpellNumber(ByVal MyNumber)
    Dim Dollars, Cents, Temp
    Dim DecimalPlace, Count
    ReDim Place(9) As String
    Place(2) = " Thousand "
    Place(3) = " Million "
    Place(4) = " Billion "
    Place(5) = " Trillion "
    ' String representation of amount.
    MyNumber = Trim(Str(MyNumber))
    ' Position of decimal place 0 if none.
    DecimalPlace = InStr(MyNumber, ".")
    ' Convert cents and set MyNumber to dollar amount.
    If DecimalPlace > 0 Then
        Cents = GetTens(Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & _
                  "00", 2))
        MyNumber = Trim(Left(MyNumber, DecimalPlace - 1))
    End If
    Count = 1
    Do While MyNumber <> ""
        Temp = GetHundreds(Right(MyNumber, 3))
        If Temp <> "" Then Dollars = Temp & Place(Count) & Dollars
        If Len(MyNumber) > 3 Then
            MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 3)
        Else
            MyNumber = ""
        End If
        Count = Count + 1
    Loop
    Select Case Dollars
        Case ""
            Dollars = "No Dollars"
        Case "One"
            Dollars = "One Dollar"
         Case Else
            Dollars = Dollars & " Dollars"
    End Select
    Select Case Cents
        Case ""
            Cents = " and No Cents"
        Case "One"
            Cents = " and One Cent"
              Case Else
            Cents = " and " & Cents & " Cents"
    End Select
    SpellNumber = Dollars & Cents
End Function

' Converts a number from 100-999 into text 
Function GetHundreds(ByVal MyNumber)
    Dim Result As String
    If Val(MyNumber) = 0 Then Exit Function
    MyNumber = Right("000" & MyNumber, 3)
    ' Convert the hundreds place.
    If Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1) <> "0" Then
        Result = GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1)) & " Hundred "
    End If
    ' Convert the tens and ones place.
    If Mid(MyNumber, 2, 1) <> "0" Then
        Result = Result & GetTens(Mid(MyNumber, 2))
    Else
        Result = Result & GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 3))
    End If
    GetHundreds = Result
End Function

' Converts a number from 10 to 99 into text. 
Function GetTens(TensText)
    Dim Result As String
    Result = ""           ' Null out the temporary function value.
    If Val(Left(TensText, 1)) = 1 Then   ' If value between 10-19...
        Select Case Val(TensText)
            Case 10: Result = "Ten"
            Case 11: Result = "Eleven"
            Case 12: Result = "Twelve"
            Case 13: Result = "Thirteen"
            Case 14: Result = "Fourteen"
            Case 15: Result = "Fifteen"
            Case 16: Result = "Sixteen"
            Case 17: Result = "Seventeen"
            Case 18: Result = "Eighteen"
            Case 19: Result = "Nineteen"
            Case Else
        End Select
    Else                                 ' If value between 20-99...
        Select Case Val(Left(TensText, 1))
            Case 2: Result = "Twenty "
            Case 3: Result = "Thirty "
            Case 4: Result = "Forty "
            Case 5: Result = "Fifty "
            Case 6: Result = "Sixty "
            Case 7: Result = "Seventy "
            Case 8: Result = "Eighty "
            Case 9: Result = "Ninety "
            Case Else
        End Select
        Result = Result & GetDigit _
            (Right(TensText, 1))  ' Retrieve ones place.
    End If
    GetTens = Result
End Function

' Converts a number from 1 to 9 into text. 
Function GetDigit(Digit)
    Select Case Val(Digit)
        Case 1: GetDigit = "One"
        Case 2: GetDigit = "Two"
        Case 3: GetDigit = "Three"
        Case 4: GetDigit = "Four"
        Case 5: GetDigit = "Five"
        Case 6: GetDigit = "Six"
        Case 7: GetDigit = "Seven"
        Case 8: GetDigit = "Eight"
        Case 9: GetDigit = "Nine"
        Case Else: GetDigit = ""
    End Select
End Function'
```

Comment: Did you write this code?

Comment: possible source https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/213360/how-to-convert-a-numeric-value-into-english-words-in-excel; c.f. [Convert numbers to word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204004/convert-numbers-to-words-with-vba/51204358#51204358)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: Most probably, not, but it is not against the rules to express his need starting from an available code wherever from it comes, I think...

Comment: @FaneDuru: You are absolutely correct. The reason I asked is so that I can gauge OPs level of understanding before offering any advice :)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: I'm afraid, if he cannot modify it by himself, his 'level of understanding' does not look being so high... If he would write the code, this modification would be piece of cake, I think... It looks that he just needs the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

The next code would do what (I understood) you need, but only for numbers without decimals. Otherwise, you must describe which are the Ringgit sub-multiples, if they are decimal divided, singular for one unit, plural for the res and so on...
You must call 'SpellNumber`function whit the second (Optional) parameter = 'True`. For Dollars, use `False` or no parameter... See and use `testSpell()` sub for testing.

```
Sub testSpell()
  Debug.Print SpellNumber(2450, True)
End Sub

'Main Function
Function SpellNumber(ByVal MyNumber, Optional RinggitCurrency As Boolean) As String
    Dim Dollars, Cents, Temp
    Dim DecimalPlace, Count
    ReDim Place(9) As String
    Place(2) = " Thousand "
    Place(3) = " Million "
    Place(4) = " Billion "
    Place(5) = " Trillion "
    ' String representation of amount.
    MyNumber = Trim(str(MyNumber))
    ' Position of decimal place 0 if none.
    DecimalPlace = InStr(MyNumber, ".")
    ' Convert cents and set MyNumber to dollar amount.
    If DecimalPlace > 0 Then
        Cents = GetTens(left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & _
                  "00", 2))
        MyNumber = Trim(left(MyNumber, DecimalPlace - 1))
    End If
    Count = 1
    Do While MyNumber <> ""
        Temp = GetHundreds(Right(MyNumber, 3), IIf(RinggitCurrency, True, False))
        If Temp <> "" Then Dollars = Temp & Place(Count) & Dollars
        If Len(MyNumber) > 3 Then
            MyNumber = left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 3)
        Else
            MyNumber = ""
        End If
        Count = Count + 1
    Loop
    Select Case Dollars
        Case ""
            Dollars = "" ' "No Dollars"
        Case "One"
            Dollars = IIf(RinggitCurrency = True, "Ringgit Malaysia one ", "One Dollar")
         Case Else
            Dollars = IIf(RinggitCurrency = True, "Ringgit Malaysia " & Dollars, Dollars & " Dollars")
    End Select
    Select Case Cents
        Case ""
            Cents = "" ' " and No Cents"
        Case "One"
            Cents = " and One Cent"
              Case Else
            Cents = " and " & Cents & " Cents"
    End Select
    SpellNumber = Dollars & Cents
End Function

' Converts a number from 100-999 into text
Function GetHundreds(ByVal MyNumber, Optional boolRinggit As Boolean = False)
    Dim Result As String
    If val(MyNumber) = 0 Then Exit Function
    MyNumber = Right("000" & MyNumber, 3)
    ' Convert the hundreds place.
    If Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1) <> "0" Then
        Result = GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1)) & " Hundred "
    End If
    ' Convert the tens and ones place.
    If Mid(MyNumber, 2, 1) <> "0" Then
        Result = Result & IIf(boolRinggit = True, "and " & GetTens(Mid(MyNumber, 2)), GetTens(Mid(MyNumber, 2)))
    Else
        Result = Result & GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 3))
    End If
    GetHundreds = Result
End Function

' Converts a number from 10 to 99 into text.
Function GetTens(TensText)
    Dim Result As String
    Result = ""           ' Null out the temporary function value.
    If val(left(TensText, 1)) = 1 Then   ' If value between 10-19...
        Select Case val(TensText)
            Case 10: Result = "Ten"
            Case 11: Result = "Eleven"
            Case 12: Result = "Twelve"
            Case 13: Result = "Thirteen"
            Case 14: Result = "Fourteen"
            Case 15: Result = "Fifteen"
            Case 16: Result = "Sixteen"
            Case 17: Result = "Seventeen"
            Case 18: Result = "Eighteen"
            Case 19: Result = "Nineteen"
            Case Else
        End Select
    Else                                 ' If value between 20-99...
        Select Case val(left(TensText, 1))
            Case 2: Result = "Twenty "
            Case 3: Result = "Thirty "
            Case 4: Result = "Forty "
            Case 5: Result = "Fifty "
            Case 6: Result = "Sixty "
            Case 7: Result = "Seventy "
            Case 8: Result = "Eighty "
            Case 9: Result = "Ninety "
            Case Else
        End Select
        Result = Result & GetDigit _
            (Right(TensText, 1))  ' Retrieve ones place.
    End If
    GetTens = Result
End Function

' Converts a number from 1 to 9 into text.
Function GetDigit(Digit)
    Select Case val(Digit)
        Case 1: GetDigit = "One"
        Case 2: GetDigit = "Two"
        Case 3: GetDigit = "Three"
        Case 4: GetDigit = "Four"
        Case 5: GetDigit = "Five"
        Case 6: GetDigit = "Six"
        Case 7: GetDigit = "Seven"
        Case 8: GetDigit = "Eight"
        Case 9: GetDigit = "Nine"
        Case Else: GetDigit = ""
    End Select
End Function '
```