# Reverse Engineering an Office Custom Toolbar

Tags: office365, ms-office, office-addins

I've "inhereited" an Excel Add-In which contains an Office 2000 custom Toolbar. Excel 365 places this on the "Add-Ins" Ribbon Tab,

I'd like to update the add-in so that the commands sit on a dedicated Ribbon Tab

While I can add a customUI to the template which creates the buttons that I need, what I can't seem to do is get at the button definitions in the custom Toolbar and find out what is actually being called when the buttons are clicked. (I have access to all the unberlying VBA - I'm just not sure how the toolbar was created)

Am I out of luck?

Answer (score 0):

Toolbars were deprecated. You need to use a ribbon XML for creating a custom UI in Office applications. Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) customizations in the following articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

See [How to add a custom Ribbon tab using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850836/how-to-add-a-custom-ribbon-tab-using-vba) for the sample code.

Comment: I'm aware that Toolbars are deprecated, which is why I want to create a Ribbon Tab. 
What I need in order to do that is be able to see the calls made by the Toolbar buttons so I can replicate them in the Ribbon buttons