# Creating custom Excel Ribbon Tab, which works in any workbook

Tags: excel, vba, server, ribbon, excel-addins

I have surfing the net for months already and haven't really found a solution to the following task I would like to perform. Here is a deal.

I am writing a bunch of code in VBA, which basically creates a new worksheet in a workbook with a specific type of calculators (there are many) for job purposes. One sheet - one type of calculator/analysis.

What I want to accomplish is, that due to increasing amount of code - I would like to put everything on to the ribbon, so I can access a macro through that. However, the job is based on to the case-to-case analysis basis, so the each new project requires a new Excel workbook to be created, where I can choose the calculator I want and do the job.

In addition to that, it requires to be launched on all computers with Excel in the network, with ability for me to be able to modify/add a code to the macro, so that all PC's can stay up-to-date simultaneously.

To wrap-up shortly:

- There is a bunch of VBA macros (which I'm constantly updating/adding);
- I need to access those macros through the Ribbon in any new workbook (not the one macro are located) on a number of computers in the network;
- There is a need to provide instant updates of the code for Ribbon and macro users.

SO, is there any solution, like - I create 2 files (one with Ribbon configuration, another with calculators) and drop them into the server folder? Each user access them once during the installation (basically locating the folder, where the addins are located), and if I need to modify something - I do it with those two files in the server folder and that's it.

If it's not real or pretty hard (for non-programmer) to instantly update all the users, the manual update can work out, but the minimum of being able to access the ribbon in each new workbook is a must.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Have you tried putting your code in an Excel Add-In?

Comment: Once you decide an Add-In (XLAM file) is the right choice and you figure out how it works, you will want to keep a read-only copy of it on the server that everyone on the network uses, and keep a local copy of it on your machine where you make all the modifications/development for it, only copying it to the server once it is fully tested (and dont forget to set it to read only again) - There's more... When the person adds your add-in to their machine, make sure they do NOT select "copy to local machine" or you will have a mess on your hands.

Comment: And unless someone else knows differently, you will have to set up their ribbon for each machine as well. I have not figured out an easy way to distribute the ribbon to the users, but would love it if someone reading this would tag me and explain how to do this without manually editing the XML from editing a ribbon export file.

Comment: **1.** Create an installer for your Add-in. Let the user install and keep a copy of the Add-In in the local machine. **2.** Your Add-In should contain a code which auto checks the server for an updated Add-In and if it finds one, simply installs the new version (overwriting the old version in the local machine). This way you will not  have to worry about deployment and re-deployment. **3.** Consider the option of converting the code to a VSTO Add-In...

Comment: @braX If you embed the XML into the .xlam file, then it *should* automatically display for all users once the Add-In is enabled, without the user needing to customise their ribbon.  [Here](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2007/03/19/sharing-a-custom-ribbon-tab-among-workbooks/) is an example of using an .xlam add-in to provide a "master" tab for other files to also use in the ribbon...

Comment: @Chronocidal Interesting... not sure exactly how to do that tho... sorry if i'm hijacking this question (i'll delete the comments later), but if you had a link handy that shows how to do that...

Comment: @braX: Here is [one way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850836/how-to-add-a-custom-ribbon-tab-using-vba) to create the Add-In. And a simple installer can be created for this Add-In

Comment: @SiddharthRout btw - the link to Custom UI Editor in that tutorial is now broken... Maybe it can be updated?

Comment: @braX: links updated :) Yes leave the comments here for the time being. Let OP also visit them if he is interested

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Thanks, I actually asked here how to do this about 4 years ago, and certainly didnt get an answer like that...

Comment: @braX: Apologies. I must have missed your question else I would have definitely replied.

Comment: An XLAM application level addin on the server containing both the ribbon XML and your VBA code is the way to go. One way to solve the update problem is to use a re-versioning addin loader that gets installed on each user PC. See http://www.decisionmodels.com/downloads/Addloader2.zip for working example code

Comment: @CharlesWilliams" something wrong with the link?

Comment: @braX Try using [Office RibbonX Editor](https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor/releases/latest) instead then

Comment: @Siddarth Rout    Thanks - try this downloads page http://www.decisionmodels.com/downloads.htm, near the bottom ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to all of you folks, who contributed on the question. Want to summarize the experience and provide the way I managed to go with it.

**1) Get your VBA code**

Let's have a code like this. It can be whatever you feel like. To do so, open VBA in the `Developers` tab or by pressing `Alt+F11`. Create a new Module, by right clicking on `VBAProject > Insert > Module`, name it `sayMsg` in the `Properties` window and enter the following code:

```
Sub saySomething()

    MsgBox "What's up?"

End Sub
```

As I said above - this module can contain anything, usually the functional part of your code, which is going to be called out in another module later.

Let's create a new module the same way we created the first one and name it `sayRibbon`. This separate module contains a call function or so called "button", which runs our subroutine from `sayMsg` module. `Copy > Paste` the code below:

```
Private Sub sayButtons(Control As IRibbonControl)

    Select Case Control.ID

        Case Is = "saySomething_Btn"
            Call saySomething
        Case Else

    End Select

End Sub
```

Basically, what we have here is a `Case` named `saySomething_Btn`, which is the "button" itself, with its defined call function.

Now `save` it as Excel Add-in file `.xlam` and `close` the program.

*Notice:* when you choose `.xlam` from a drop down menu, you will automatically be located in default `Microsoft > AddIns` folder. In order to save it on your `Desktop`, first of all choose the file type, and then relocate the folder.

**2) XML map by [Office RibbonX Editor](https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor/releases/tag/v1.6)**

The utility above provides you with the option to create a custom tab in the Excel ribbon. Follow the link for download. All installation and use instructions are also available by that link.

- After you finish with an install, open `OfficeRibbonXEditor.exe` file.
- `File > Open` your `.xlam` file. Now it appeared in the list below.
- `Right click > Insert Office 2010+ CustomUI Part` (or `Insert Office 2007 CustomUI Part` - depends on the Office version you are running).
- `Copy > Paste` the code below:

> Code

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" xmlns:Q="sayRibbon">
<ribbon startFromScratch="false">
<tabs>
<tab idQ = "Q:rxTabUI" label="Say Something" insertAfterMso="TabView">
<group idQ="Q:rxGrpUI" label="Say">
<button id="saySomething_Btn" label="Say Something" onAction="sayButtons" />
</group>
</tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

- Press `Validate`, in case of issues - the error message will appear (Debug if needed, but you shouldn't in this case).
- Now `Save` and `Close` the Ribbon Editor. You can only save, when `.xlam` is not opened by Excel.

**3) Access the .xlam Add-In in any WorkBook**

The main purpose of such approach was to provide an easy access to the VBA code from any Workbook in Excel and from any machine in the corporate network without actually installing it separately on each individual computer.

It doesn't really matter - do you want to get access only on your PC or local network, the installation process is the same.

- Place `.xlam` file to any location of your choice (local folder or server).
- Go to `Excel > File > Options > Add-Ins`.
- Press `Go...` button below, `Browse` for the `.xlam` location and press `OK`.
- Ensure the Add-In is marked in a list. Press `OK`.

*Notice*: I would recommend to `encrypt your VBA` for security reasons, in case if you want to be the one, who actually can edit the code - to eliminate any issues, which may arise if VBA code isn't encrypted.

I have checked the performance on my corporate network, the results are quite satisfying. All the changes you perform in the code are instantly updated among all users after they restart their Excel application.

Don't forget to release the change notes and to keep at least couple of older versions available for people, in case of need or emergency.

As long as the project will evolve, maybe more complex approaches could be used, however due to boundaries I am currently facing, this approach provides the best performance at the moment.

Comment: this is very useful