# Add custom tab in the ribbon

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to learn something new. I have created a custom tab based on Siddharth Rout' tutorial.
The XML part is like that

```html
<customUI onLoad="RibbonOnLoad" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<ribbon startFromScratch="false">
<tabs>
<tab id="MyCustomTab" label="MyTab" insertAfterMso="TabView">
<group id="customGroup1" label="First Tab">
<button id="customButton1" label="JG Button 1" imageMso="HappyFace" size="large" onAction="Callback1" />
<button id="customButton2" label="JG Button 2" imageMso="PictureBrightnessGallery" size="large" onAction="Callback2" />
</group>
</tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Then in workbook module I put this code so as to activate the tab when the workbook is open

```
Private myRibbon As IRibbonUI

Sub OnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
Set myRibbon = ribbon
myRibbon.ActivateTabMso ("MyTab")
End Sub
```

But when I opened the workbook, I encountered an error `Can't run the macro RibbonOnLoad`. I am using Office 365 32 Bit and Windows 10 64 Bit.

Comment: To start, the OnLoad and OnAction items of the CustomUI specify the names of the VBA Methods that will be called. Thus your 'Sub OnLoad(....' method really needs to be 'Sub RibbonOnLoad(...)

Comment: I tried `RibbonOnLoad` and saved closed wb then I got the same error. I tried to change `myRibbon.ActivateTab ("MyTab")` and removed the so part, saved an closed then I got the same error.

Comment: Are you using the CustomUI editor?  https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-custom-ui-editor

Comment: Yes I am using CustomUI Editor.

Comment: Sorry was watching a TV Series. This is the reason why I recommend creating a question rather than following up in comments. This way whoever is online and can answer, will answer your question. Glad it is resolved! :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thank you very much. I really like and enjoy your awesome posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as freeflow has already mentioned, the callback should be `RibbonOnLoad`.  Secondly, you should be using the ActivateTab method, since it's a custom tab.  And thirdly, you should be specifying the control ID, not the tab name.  Try the following code, which needs to be placed in a regular module...

```
Private myRibbon As IRibbonUI

'Callback for customUI.onLoad
Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)

    Set myRibbon = ribbon
    myRibbon.ActivateTab "MyCustomTab"

End Sub
```

Comment: Would it better to put the code in standard module or ThisWorkbook open event..? Currently I am putting it in the Workbook Open event.

Comment: When I put it in Workbook Open, I got the same error. Then I tried something else, is to put the code in standard module, and convert Private to Public. This works and no error but I didn't get the custom tab activated.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now solved. I missed the remark if using the Tab ID not the Tab name. But what if I need to use the Tab name?

Comment: You can set up a Select Case statement to return and assign a variable the corresponding control ID.  Then you can pass the variable to the ActivateTab method.

Comment: Can you please show an example as I am new at this aspect?

Comment: In this case, though, I don't think it would be practical.  `RibbonOnLoad` runs automatically when the workbook is opened.  So you either hard code the tab name or prompt the user.  However, if you're going to hard code the tab name, why not just use the ID.  Or, if you're going to prompt the user, how practical would it be?

Comment: OK. You are more logical at this point. Thanks a lot for great help.