# How do I add a new tab to excel with my macros through an add in

Tags: excel, vba, add-in, ribbon, excel-addins

I know I can add a new tab to the excel ribbon through the customize ribbon functionality but I want to do it through an add-in I can easily distribute. I have attached an example of what this looks like from another extension. Even pointing me to some useful documentation would be helpful.

Also for creating basic GUIs with add ins are userforms the simplest way?

THanks
[image: Image of an existing add on]

Comment: You can use the [Custom UI Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850836/how-to-add-a-custom-ribbon-tab-using-vba) and then save that file as an Addin which you can distribute

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for thank you!

Comment: `This is pretty much what I was looking for thank you! – Justin Jones 14 mins ago` Closed it as a duplicate.