# Customized menu in excel

Tags: excel, vba, menu

I have an excel worksheet that has several macros within it.  I have created a custome menu.  When I click on the button, I get an error message with an older file name of the worksheet.  When I run the macros from the VBA editor, they work.  This file is saved on a network drive for the associates in my department to access.  How do I get the macros to run when the button is pressed?

I have attempted to access the file from the network drive and recreate the custom menu from another PC.  Still getting the same error.

Comment: What kind of menu are we talking about? - and what exactly is the error message. If you want help you need to give us something concrete to work with

Comment: I created a Dept tab with 3 option.  Create report, delete report and Print report.  The file is saved as current date Completed Reports.  It is giving me a file name that is weeks old.  Like the name is buffered.  When I execute the vba modules directly from the editor window they worik as they should.  Only the custom buttons are giving me the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a ribbon element to an excel workbook, you have tutorial here:

[How to add a custom Ribbon tab using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850836/how-to-add-a-custom-ribbon-tab-using-vba)