# Adding External Application Buttons to Custom UI Ribbon Bar in Word 365

Tags: xml, vba, ms-word, acrobat

I'm currently working on customising my **UI ribbon bar in Word 365**, and I'm wondering if there's a way to add external application buttons, specifically **Acrobat Add-in buttons**, to my custom tab.

The goal is to consolidate all my frequently used buttons into one tab for seamless accessibility. Since Acrobat provides useful buttons within its Add-in, I'm curious if there's a method to "call" or integrate these buttons into my XML code for the custom UI ribbon.

I revised Adobe forums, VBA forums, Word forums, YT videos and nobody mentions this at all. I have seen this on a MS 2007 custom tab and I believe it should be possible to replicate for 365. Picture attached of what I am expecting to reproduce (this is extracted from MS 2007 or older) [Custom UI ribbon tab with Acrobat buttons in DD - MS 2007](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbLLj.png)

Has anyone successfully achieved this or has insights into how it can be done? Your guidance on this matter would be highly appreciated!

This is what I am trying right now but still not working.
Tried 'button' instead of 'control' didn't work either.
Not sure how to include this buttons into the 'PDF group'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" 
            xmlns:x1="PDFMarker.OfficeAddin"
            onLoad="RibbonControl.Onload">
                
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
     <tab id="CustomTab1" insertBeforeMso="HelpTab" label="Toolbar" > 
         
       <group id="CustGrp1" label="PDF">
            <button idMso="FileSaveAsPdfOrXps" size="normal" />
            <button idMso="FileEmailAsPdfEmailAttachment" size="normal" />
  
            <control idQ="x1:ACROBAT_ACTIONS_BUTTON" visible="true"/>
            <control idQ="x1:ACROBAT_ImportComments" visible="true"/>
            <control idQ="x1:ACROBAT_EmailPDF" visible="true"/>
            <control idQ="x1:ACROBAT_Embed_Media" visible="true"/>
    </group>
      <group id="CustGrp2" label="Headings" >
            <button id="Btn1" label="H1" 
                    onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
            <button id="Btn2" label="H2" 
                    onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
            <button id="Btn3" label="H3" 
                    onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
            <button id="Btn4" label="H4" 
                    onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
            <button id="Btn5" label="H5" 
                    onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
    </group>
     </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using for this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: IMHO this is tricky even when you use the MS supplied buttons.  ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850836/how-to-add-a-custom-ribbon-tab-using-vba/67460894#67460894

Comment: @user10186832, I have edited the question and added the code. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Read this link about [How do I get the Create PDF button to appear in WORD and EXCEL banner?](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/how-do-i-get-the-create-pdf-button-to-appear-in-word-and-excel-banner/td-p/10335848) which makes it look as though if you have a paid for Adobe PDF application it may be possible using an Adobe add-in and using the Excel UI. Perhaps what you want would be possible using this approach.

Comment: [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/get-the-adobe-acrobat-tab-to-appear-b83cbba3-7bc1-4c75-b8dc-511e07a283f0) is the same method from the Microsoft point of view.

Comment: [Troubleshoot Acrobat PDFMaker issues in Microsoft Office on Windows](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/acrobat/kb/troubleshoot-acrobat-pdfmaker-problems-office.html)

Comment: [Specifying Ribbon Image Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/windowsribbon/windowsribbon-imageformats?redirectedfrom=MSDN#sizes)