# VBA: How to test macros launched from custom ribbons?

Tags: xml, vba, excel, ribbon

Using the [Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/08/07/7293.aspx), using Excel 365, I added a custom group to a ribbon using this code:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>

      <tab idMso="TabHome" >
        <group id="customGroup1" label="My Group" insertAfterMso="GroupEditingExcel">

          <button id="customButton1" label="Click Me" size="large" 
        onAction="Macro1()" imageMso="HappyFace" />
        </group>
      </tab>

    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

When I run the macros from this button, I get several error messages. (But not when I run it from the Macros windows or any other way.)  I'd like to step through the code, but it ignores breakpoints and Stop commands.

Is there a way to step through the code when launched this way?

EDIT: A possible clue:  this fellow was having one of the same errors I am: [Calling an excel macro from the ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107507/calling-an-excel-macro-from-the-ribbon). To apply the same remedy I'd have to add 
`control As IRibbonControl` to my `Sub custombutton1()`. But if I *have* a `Sub custombutton1()`, I don't know where it is.

EDIT: Never mind; I learned that this is a "Callback" that I have to add to a module. Now the macro runs fine. However, I'd still like an answer to my original question: How can I step through the code to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure "Macro1()" is on module level, should solve your issues.